# Google Assistant account linking with Keycloak

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, keycloak, dialogflow-es-fulfillment, account-linking

I am building a Dialogflow agent and I am trying to have 
[account linking with OAuth](https://developers.google.com/actions/identity/oauth2) 
between my website and Google Assistant. And I am using Keycloak as my authentification server.

**Keycloak configuration**

[image: Keycloak configuration]

**Account Linking**
[image: Account Linking]

**Result**

[image: result]

**Then after I put the username and password**
[image: result]

Any Ideas why Google assistant does not sgin in? And is there a way to debug it?

Comment: Can you update this question to indicate what you've tried so far? Please also see: [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I have just updated my question. @MaxWiederholt

Comment: Have you tried following the recommended procedure for account linking? You can find extensive documentation, as well as the pros and cons of different methods, at https://developers.google.com/actions/identity/

Comment: Yes, I have been following the documentation. That is how I got to that problem.